# Can we write an expression for the constant in the quadratic equation such that changing $b$ results in a pure horizontal shift?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I know this sounds completely strange but I've been pondering this question I've created and I'm not sure how to approach it. With the standard quadratic form $ax^2+bx+c$, modifying only $b$ value results in a horizontal and vertical shift. Is there a way to write the constant $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ such that modifying the $b$ coefficient in $ax^2+bx+c$ results in a pure horizontal shift?

Answer (score 2):

If you complete the square of the quadratic, you get
$$ax^2+bx+c=a\bigg(x+\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
Thus if you let
$$c=\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
you have
$$ax^2+bx+c=a\bigg(x+\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2$$
and in this case, a change in $b$ results in a horizontal shift only.

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm not sure how this would work considering now you have written an equation rather than an express which is a function of x (i.e. y equals)

Comment: Oh, that's okay... if we let
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
and
$$ax^2+bx+c=a\bigg(x+\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2$$
since we are letting $c=\frac{b^2}{4a}$, it follows that
$$f(x)=a\bigg(x+\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

A quadratic polynomial

$$p(x) = a x^2 + bx + c$$

can be shifted $k$ units to the right as $p(x+k)$, i.e. we get the new polynomial

$$p_k(x) = a (x+k)^2 + b(x+k) + c$$

We see that

$$p_k(x) = ax^2+ ak^2+ 2akx + bx + bk + c = ax^2 + (2ak+b)x + (ak^2+bk+c)$$

Comment: Thank you, however this isn't quite what I'm asking. For example if $a$ is 1, then $c$ by completing the square is $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$. By changing the value of b, I want the parabola to shift only left and right by finding some constant value that works for any a, not just a=1. Thanks again.